# Option for vertical auto alignment of large labels in chronosys timeline

Tags: chronology

The timeline

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Biographical cornerstones}
\startchronology[startyear=1850,stopyear=1950,height=0.5ex]
%\chronoevent{1858}{\parbox{5cm}{Publication of Darwin's Evolutionary Theory}}
%\chronoevent{1883}{\parbox{5cm}{born in the Austrian part of Austrian part of Austria-Hungary}}
\chronoevent{1858}{Publication of Darwin's Evolutionary Theory}
\chronoevent{1883}{born in the Austrian part of Austrian part of Austria-Hungary}
\chronoevent{1950}{died 1950 in USA}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

looks like this: [image]

(pdf screenshot with borders of okular reader in 100 % zoom)

Following issues arise:

- How to keep labels on the page (line breaks should be calculated automatically)? Adding the parbox (in comments) helps but it might break the alignment of the following issue (so I commented it out in order to indicate that it is not mandatory).
- How to fix vertical alignment so that it looks like in chronosys documentation (http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/chronosys/docchronosys_en.pdf) in section 3.3.2.1 (where I don't see how to achieve this layout)?

Comment: I know that it is a little late in time to answer this, but thought I would give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the options `textwidth` and  `markdepth`. I do not think there is a mechanism for automatic application of those parameters.  In `chronosys` they have to be applied to each `chronoevent`. As applied to your MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chronosys}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{Biographical cornerstones}
\startchronology[startyear=1850,stopyear=1950,height=0.5ex]
%\chronoevent{1858}{\parbox{5cm}{Publication of Darwin's Evolutionary Theory}}
%\chronoevent{1883}{\parbox{5cm}{born in the Austrian part of Austrian part of Austria-Hungary}}
\chronoevent[textwidth=4cm]{1858}{Publication of Darwin's Evolutionary Theory}
\chronoevent[textwidth=4.5cm,markdepth=50pt]{1883}{born in the Austrian part of Austrian part of Austria-Hungary}
\chronoevent{1950}{died 1950 in USA}
\stopchronology

\end{document}
```

Produces the following:

[image]